# iframe inside of a div which populates data from the server. I have to scroll inside of the iframe when i still have real estate on my page

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

Here's my div and my iframe:

```
<div class="divMinorView">
    <!-- Selected order-->
    <iframe id="ifMinor" src="#"></iframe>
</div>
```

Also inside the iframe I have this table, it populates rows of data, sometimes 10 rows, maybe 50 to 100 at times.:

```
<table id="slot_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="slot_rows">
    <?php if (count($slots) == 0): ?>
        <tr class="none">
            <td colspan=9>No slots found in that minor code.</td>
        </tr>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach ($slots as $slot): ?>
            <tr <?php if ($slot->is_expired($end_db_fmt)) { echo 'class="expired"'; } ?>>
                <td class="actions">
                    <?php if (!$slot->is_expired($end_db_fmt)): ?>
                        <span class="expire_slot">X</span>
                        <span class="expire_error faux_links tip" data-tip="There has been an error"><img src="/images/thumbs_down_ico.png" width="13" height="13"></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <select id="new_style" name="style">
            <?php foreach ($style_list as $style): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $style->get_id(); ?>"><?php echo $style->get_desc(); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="ints"><input id="new_price" type="text" name="price_point" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="add_slot" id="add_slot" value="Add slot"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried setting the css to `height:100%;` as well as setting `body{ margin:0; }`
I've tried setting the iframe id to `scrolling="no"`.

I'm not sure why I can't get the data to populate to the bottom of the screen. It shouldn't need to scroll, unless maybe the data being populated fills up all the real estate on the page than scroll.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Should i be using some jquery to fix the height issues?

```
$("iframe").height($("#divMinorView").height());

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("iframe").height($("#divMinorView").height());
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use an iframe if you serve the content from the same domain?

Comment: you can't manipulate the content of an iframe with a "local" css file. you have to use javascript.

Comment: No, there isn't really a solid reason for having the content in an iframe, it's being served from the same domain. yes.

Comment: I had an idea i might need to use javascript or jquery. Thanks Razhial.